# EditText that can regain focus

Tags: android

I want to set my editText to always focus and when I inputted something and press key enter it will clear and regain focus again and can be inputted again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can capture the enter key event of your EditText, pull the text from it, and then set the text to "".

Here it is;

```
EditText et;
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>(); // I am not sure how
     // you want to save the strings, but this is a good way.
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et); // fill in your id here
    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, 
            int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            actionId = (actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION);
            switch (actionId){
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                if (etAddLike.getText().length() > 0){
                    input.add(et.getText().toString());
                    etAddLike.setText("");
                }
                return true;
            default: 
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    ...
```

don't forget to accept answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

call `edittext.requestFocus();` when you want focus on it